# PWM strategy for motor with variable load

Tags: pwm, dc-motor, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi and PWM motor controller driving a DAGU chassis with tracks. The driven wheels each have their own 8-pole encoder on them, and I count a rising or falling edge as a 'tick'. So there are 22.5 degrees/tick. The motors are geared 48:1.

The tracks and wheels give uneven load to the motor every full rotation. In other words, over the course of a full rotation the motor (or your hand) will find the tracks easier to turn at some points, and harder at others. This is due to the wheels/treads being a bit out of round.

This results in my PWM loop oscillating as well. I'm not sure how to "tune" this out though. First thought is to calculate the error over a longer period of time, but then the motors take forever to get up to speed.

Is there a general strategy for this, or should I just use something like:

```
if motor is stopped
  use fast PWM rate
otherwise if motor has been moving for a while
  use a slower rate
```

Apologies if this is the incorrect SE site. I wasn't sure if here or SO would be correct.

Main Loop:

```
    #define MOTOR_TICK_DELAY    1000000000LL //1000ms
    motorA.target = 1.5;
    motorB.target = 1.5;

    debug("Standby off.\n");
    bcm2835_gpio_set(STBY);

    struct timespec time;
    uint64_t cTime = 0, lTime = 0, refreshTime = 0, lTimeA = 0, lTimeB = 0;
    int timeCount = 0;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &time);
    lTime = time.tv_sec * MOTOR_TICK_DELAY + time.tv_nsec;

    while (quit == 0)
    {
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &time);
        cTime = time.tv_sec * MOTOR_TICK_DELAY + time.tv_nsec;
        refreshTime = cTime - lTime;

        motorUpdate(&motorA, &cTime, &lTimeA);
        motorUpdate(&motorB, &cTime, &lTimeB);

        if (refreshTime > REFRESH_SPEED)
        {//Refresh the ncurses output}
    }
```

Motor PWM calculation method:

```
void motorUpdate(struct Motor* motor, uint64_t* cTime, uint64_t* lTime)
{
    if (encoderTick(motor->encoderPin)) ++motor->encoderCount;

    uint64_t dt = (uint64_t)(*cTime) - (uint64_t)(*lTime);

    if (dt > MOTOR_TICK_DELAY)
    {
        //debug("ctime: %llu\n", *cTime);
        //debug("ltime: %llu\n", *lTime);
        //debug("diff: %llu\n", dt);

        //actual speed = tick count / (dt in ???seconds)
        motor->actual = (float)motor->encoderCount / (dt / 100000000LL);
        motor->encoderCount = 0; //TODO need rolling average
        *lTime = *cTime; //reset motor last tick time

        //calculate raw PWM
        motor->lastError = motor->error;
        motor->error = (motor->target - motor->actual);
        motor->dError = motor->error - motor->lastError;
        motor->iError += motor->error;
        motor->pwm = (motor->error * 75 + motor->iError * 120 + motor->dError * 5);
        //motor->pwm = (motor->error * 50 + motor->iError * 100 + motor->dError * 10); //pretty smooth, takes a while
        //motor->pwm = (motor->error * 60 + motor->iError * 120 + motor->dError * 10); //a bit jerky, but doesn't overshoot

        //clamp PWM
        if (motor->pwm > PWM_RANGE) motor->pwm = PWM_RANGE;
        else if (motor->pwm < 0) motor->pwm = 0;

        //set PWM
        bcm2835_pwm_set_data(motor->pwmChannel, motor->pwm);
    }
}
```

Full code is also available here: https://github.com/nearwood/rpi-drd/blob/master/controller/src/controller.c

Comment: What speed (in terms of stiff-easy-stiff per second) are you aiming for? Do you have position/speed feedback, or are you doing open loop control? If you do, what's your sensor bandwidth?

Comment: How is the loop closed?

Comment: I've updated the question with encoder information. It's closed loop. There's no real speed I'm aiming for. The motors will drive the tracks at a max of about 50rpm in the air. I'd like to be able to utilize, say, anywhere from 10-40 rpm (the desired speed will eventually be remote controlled).

Comment: (1) Are the encoders single channel or dual? (2) Are the encoders on the wheels or on the motors? Motors would be 48 times better.

Comment: can you post the code for your PID algorithm?

Comment: The encoders are on the wheels.

Comment: @Nick: Why did you only answer one of my questions? I numbered them so you would see there are two!

Comment: @Transistor I am researching what you mean by one or two channel :). But here, this will probably be clearer: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12629

Comment: @Techydude I have added all the relevant code, I believe.

Comment: @Nick: most encoders use two channels in quadrature (90° apart) so that they can measure both speed and direction. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, add a feedforward loop with LUT. For first experiment a LUT can be calculated as \$ U_{static}= k_{PWM}\cdot k_u\cdot v_{SP}\$ Where \$k_u\$ is the motor constant  \$[\dfrac{V}{rpm}]\$, \$v\$ is the speed \$[rpm]\$, \$U_{static}\$ are %PWM and \$k_{PWM}\$ is a constant of your H-bridge \$[\dfrac{\% PWM}{V}]\$
You can tune whatever controller with Ziegler-Nichols method. At very low speed your encoder is not capable to deliver good information, so you can implement a switch that disables the controller. Begin to set up with small steps, first use P-controller only, then turn to PI, PID could be just a headache. IMO the P-controler is what will suit your demand.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Figure 1. This is the Wheel Encoder Kit from DAGU, a simple add-on to any wheeled robot that can help measure the speed or distance the chassis travels. Each wheel encoder kit consists of two neodymium 8-pole magnets with rubber hubs and two hall-effect sensors terminated with 150mm cables and 3-pin female servo headers. These wheel encoders require a supply voltage of 3-24V with a supply current of 4mA. Source: [Sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12629).*

The encoder has 8 poles. The encoder comes with two sensors so by putting these an odd multiple of 360/16 = 22.5° apart we can double the number of pulses and double the encoder resolution from 8 to 16 pulses per revolution.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fna2Nf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. Using two sensors we can double the resolution.*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fk69Px.png)</sup>

*Figure 3. Getting 32 pulses per revolution is possible using two sensors and both rising and falling edge detection.*

By offsetting the sensors an odd multiple of 360/32 = 11.25° apart you could sense 32 encoder edges per revolution. This will take two micro inputs per encoder and a little debouncing and edge detection code but should not be too difficult.

This may not solve all your problems but it should make them at least four times easier.